# About datagrid-view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

net.I created a checkbox column in data grid-view and call the checked value.If i unchecked and checked another row it shows error.Need to know how to write loop concept for this.

Comment: It shows you an error that you want help with but you decided not to show it to us? Not the best course of action.

Comment: "object reference not set to an instance of object" this came when i unchecked the checkbox and rechecked the other value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should have a datagridview that has a checkbox column, and how you should access it:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Name")
dt.Columns.Add("Age", GetType(integer))
dt.Columns.Add("IsActiveMember", GetType(Boolean))

dt.Rows.Add("Siva", 32 , True)
dt.Rows.Add("Siva2", 32 , False)
dt.Rows.Add("Siva3", 33 , True)

yourdatagridview.DataSource = dt
```

i.e. you create a datatable to hold your data, fill it and bind it. the datagridview will create the columns automatically.

When you want to retrieve the checked boxes:

```
For Each ro as DataRow in DirectCast(yourdatagridview.DataSource, DataTable).Rows
  If DirectCast(ro("IsActiveMember"), Boolean) Then
      Messageox.Show(ro("Name") & " is an active member")
  Else
      Messageox.Show(ro("Name") & " is not an active member")
  End If

Next ro
```

If you get tired of directcasting all the time, add a new DataSet object to your project and use a stringly typed dataset

Comment: i am importing the excel file to data grid-view then selecting values from dg-view to ppt presentation

Comment: here is the sample

Comment: For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("checkbox").Value)

            If isSelected Then

                With opres

                    With .Slides(1)

                        With .Shapes("Table1")

                            .Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = row.Cells("Plant").Value.ToString

Comment: Put your excel data in a DataTable. DataGridVIEW is for showing data, not storing it